# rich editor - get value

Tags: javascript, dojo, rich-text-editor

I am trying to get the value of dojo editor and append it to the hidden input. This code:

```
onClick="dojo.byId('editorContent').value = this.getValue()
```

works correctly if i put it in the div of the editor. However i want to update before send the form the hidden input. I already tried with onclick and onsubmit but didn't works. 
Probably this is wrong  :

```
content.getValue()
```

**code**

```
<form>  
  <div id="descricao_oferta">
        <input type="hidden" name="item[editorContent]" id='editorContent' />
        <div dojoType="dijit.Editor" id="content" height='200px'">
        <?php echo isset($arr['conteudo']) ? $arr['conteudo'] : "Descrição";?>
    </div>
<form>

    <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Registo" onClick="dojo.byId('editorContent').value = content.getValue()"/>

</form>
```

How can i update the hidden input with the content of the editor when submit the form ?

[similar problem](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-to-submit-dojo-editor-contents-with-form-submission-td3305233.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[source](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/tests/editor/test_Editor.html)

this is the correct way:

```
onClick="dojo.byId('editorContent').value = dijit.byId('content').get('value')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `dijit.Editor.get('value');` to get the value from the editor?

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/editor/